# REGEX not working at Upstart script

Tags: bash, scripts, upstart

For Upstart Script, regex always gives me false, however it does work once I run script manually.

/etc/init/sync_remote_users.conf:

```
start on filesystem and net-device-up IFACE!=lo
stop on runlevel [016]
respawn
##?
respawn limit 20 5
##?

script
    exec opt/local/our-sync-pkg-2.0/sync_users start
end script
```

Here is sync_users code:

```
#!/bin/bash

for line in $(cat $DECRYPTED_PASSWORDS_FILE)
do
    if [[ !($line =~ ^[^-_][0-9a-zA-Z._-@]+\:[0-9a-zA-Z.\/$]{98}+$) ]]; then
        result=false;
   fi
done
```

Comment: Hi. Well - for starters, I'd say the problem is with your $DECRYPTED_PASSWORDS_FILE variable. What is it actually? I don't see it defined anywhere? So I guess you define it manually in your shell and then you execute your script - and it works, fine. But later when you try to execute it from your upstart script (why actually you also use "start" argument for your sync_users script, if it doesn't take arguments as far as I see?) - your script doesn't know what this variable is. Hence it fails always - because the "cat" command's output isn't anything useful for you.

Comment: BTW - I think it would be probably better for you, if your bash script could take filename as argument - for the file you want to "analyze" with your regexp - instead of declaring the file as your shell variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code was working fine, Problem was that upstart script didn't run BASH scripts by default, un less u mention it is bash script. So i change my upstart script to this:

```
start on filesystem and net-device-up IFACE!=lo
stop on runlevel [016]

script
    exec bash -c '/opt/local/our-sync-pkg-2.0/sync_users start'
end script
```